# RoR Facebook Canvas App user Registraton & Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, canvas

I'm currently working on a RoR app that is only going to be used inside the Facebook Canvas. To model the users I use Devise. Now, I'm aiming at making the signup & login process easy as pie. If my prospective users open the app, he/she should be prompted to authorize the app to access name and email. If this happens a user should be created with the name, fb_uid and email. Every time this user now comes back to the canvas app he should be signed in.
How do I accomlish this?
Please help - looked at koala, omniauth, the javascript and php sdks -> my brain just feels fried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This railscasts episode shows you how to easily put together the authentication system using omniauth-facebook. I actually just used it today as well. Let me know if you have any more specific questions.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

Comment: the railscast episode is a nice helper, but with devise it's not the go to solution. still working on it, will post update once done.

Comment: Use 'rails g migration AddColumnsToUsers uid provider oauth_token oauth_expires_at:datetime' instad of "rails g model user provider uid name oauth_token oauth_expires_at:datetime". The rest of the railscast should be the same for devise.